# Getting null pointer exception while getting from mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, spring, rest

Hello all i am using rest and mysql as my db.

Below is my rest get code for getting allbooks(Resource)

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getBooks(@QueryParam("format") String format) {

    //line35: return Response.status(Status.OK).entity((new GenericEntity<List<Book>>(bookService.getAllBooks()) {
    })).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "XML".equalsIgnoreCase(format)
            ? MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=UTF-8" : MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=UTF-8").build();

}
```

Below is my service

```
public List<Book> getAllBooks() {

    //books service line 24 return new ArrayList<Book>(booksDao.getAllBooks());
    /* return new ArrayList<Book>(books.values()); */
}
```

BooksDAO class

```
public class BooksDAO {

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    //books dao line24: return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from books.books_table", new RowMapper<Book>() {

        @Override
        public Book mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {
            Book e = new Book();
            e.setId(rs.getInt(1));

            e.setName(rs.getString(2));

            e.setPrice(rs.getString(3));

            e.setAuthor(rs.getString(4));

            return e;
        }


    });
}
```

Below is my bean.I am using springJDBC

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  

<bean id="ds" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx" />  
<property name="username" value="xxxx" />  
<property name="password" value="xxxx" />  
</bean>  

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="edao" class="com.nag.library.database.BooksDAO">  
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
</bean>  

</beans>
```

Without connecting to db i am fine getting the json/xml response but when i connect db its throwing a nullpointer exception

```
Aug 16, 2016 10:43:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
invoke     
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.nag.library.database.BooksDAO.getAllBooks(BooksDAO.java:24)
at com.nag.library.service.BookService.getAllBooks(BookService.java:24)
at com.nag.library.resource.BookResource.getBooks(BookResource.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Where i'm doing the thing wrong.Please guide me.

Thank you

Comment: On which instruction have you the NPE ?
You should show all BooksDAO class

Comment: NPE?Can you elaborate it.I am sorry i am just a learner.

Comment: no problem : NPE=NullPointerException

Comment: I have update the booksdao class i get the null pointer exception while returning the jdbc.query in my books dao.When i wrote a main menthod and executed i got all the values from table.But i am unable to return the same to a rest

Comment: "com.nag.library.database.BooksDAO.getAllBooks(BooksDAO.java:24)" This means the error occurs on line 24 of `BooksDAO.java`. Which line is that?

Comment: `code`return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from books.books_table", new RowMapper<Book>() {

        @Override
        public Book mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rownumber) throws SQLException {
            Book e = new Book();
            e.setId(rs.getInt(1));

            e.setName(rs.getString(2));

            e.setPrice(rs.getString(3));

            e.setAuthor(rs.getString(4));

            return e;
        }


    });
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your service is not a bean managed by Spring since not declared in your spring conf.
So you don't use these beans  :

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">  
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="edao" class="com.nag.library.database.BooksDAO">  
<property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>  
</bean>
```

And as consequence, your `jdbcTemplace` is `null` in your `BooksDAO`which you use at the runtime.
add your service as a bean in this configuration and add to it the bean `edao` as a property.
You should also wire your service with your rest class.

**Edit for precision** : I think that the problem is here because in this line `return jdbcTemplate.query("‌​select * from books.books_table", new RowMapper<Book>()` the NullPointerException can have a single cause : jdbcTemplate is null. Besides, you don't declare the service bean in his configuration. Besides, no instruction in the method body may trigger a NPE. –

Comment: He told before that the instace of jdbcTemplate was not null, i thought the same as you before but if it's aproblem declaring the beans, how is the call reaching the dao if the instance on the service class is not getting autowired?

Comment: Not logic. in this line     `return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from books.books_table", new RowMapper<Book>()` the nullpointer can have a single cause : `jdbcTemplate is null`.
Besides, he doesn't declare the service bean in his configuration. Besides, no instruction in the method body may trigger a NPE.

Comment: I didn't see you edited your comment. Maybe, he instantiates it with a `new()` or maybe he use another instance of the dao which is autowired. Sincerely, I don't know but the  NPE is a bean wiring problem, no a SQL problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've something wrong on your mapping at the dao, can you post the code with line numbers to be sure about my suspicius?, wihtout the line numbers we cannot be sure about the line with the Nullpointer (24).

Firstly If I were you, I would try to map the fields of your table by name (getString("COLUMN_NAME")) instead of index, to check if there is something wrong with the columns (index or data_type).

Finally if this don't work, try to map an empty object as the mapper result, to check if it's a problem with the query.

Greatings

Comment: When i wrote a main method and executed i got all the values from table.But i am unable to return the same to a rest

Comment: this is strange because the error is executing the query, do you use diferent configuration xmls ?

Comment: Hopefully yes when i print the object it is returning the values

Comment: No i didnt use anything different its the same.

Comment: Ok, can you use this method http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String- instead your current method to check if a differnet trace apear

Comment: Can you try to put the sentence in diferent lines to check witch part is the wonrg one, or debug the line. I think there is something on your log configuration that is hiding the true error from the stack trace, because for that looks a problem accesing de database (if the instance of the template is no null), or to the table, but this don't explain how it works on your main program